# Syncfusion DoubleTextBox Convert Input from User

Tags: c#, wpf, decimal, converters, syncfusion

we got a problem which we are currently working on.
We want to use a DoubleTextBox from syncfusion or a similar WPF-Element.
The Issue is:

The user should be able to type 345 in the field and it got automatic corrected to 3.45
If he types 35 it should be 0.35
If he types 4.56 it should be 4.56
So far we implemented a Converter for the binding which do this very well.
But if the value is entered through database as a decimal value like 300 which ist 300.00
the converter look for the point "." -> didn't find it and place one so 300 is now 3.00
This is wrong. 
If the database value is 312.45 it works well. The decimal cut off all zero digits :/

We are currently not able to use our converter for this.

Does anyone has an idea for our problem? Is there a WPF-Element from syncfusion which does this so far?

This is the converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(object))
        {
            // Formatierung bei Eingabefeldern
            if (value != null)
            {
                string result = String.Empty;

                result = value.ToString();
                if (!value.ToString().Contains(","))
                {
                    decimal _formatted = System.Convert.ToDecimal(value) / 100;

                    result = _formatted.ToString("F");
                }
                else if (value.ToString().Contains(","))
                {
                    decimal _formatted = System.Convert.ToDecimal(value);

                    result = string.Format("{0:F2}", _formatted);
                }

                return result.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Formatierung bei nicht Eingabefeldern
            if (value == String.Empty)
            {
                value = 0;
            }

            decimal _formattedcomputed = System.Convert.ToDecimal(value);
            string resultcomputed = string.Format("{0:F2}", _formattedcomputed);

            return resultcomputed;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please share code for the converter and the viewmodel property. It sounds like your viewmodel property might be a string.

Comment: My viewmodelproperty is a decimal.

Comment: Do you have a ConvertBack method too?

Comment: I'm seeing some worrying signs here: You assign value.ToString() to `result`. Then you check if `value.ToString()` contains ',', then you have an else that checks if `value.ToString()` *doesn't* contain ','. Finally, you return `result.ToString()`. This is code written by somebody who wasn't paying any attention to what he was doing.

Comment: Oh, and half the locals are painstakingly given a leading `_` to indicate that they're private fields. The re-parsed decimal goes in a local named `_formatted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working correctly for me.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        // Formatierung bei Eingabefeldern
        if (value != null)
        {
            string inputStr = value.ToString();
            decimal inputDecimal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(value);

            if (inputStr.Contains(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator))
            {
                return inputDecimal.ToString("F2");
            }
            else
            {
                inputDecimal /= 100;

                return inputDecimal.ToString("F");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(
            String.Format("Error converting value {0}: {1}", value, ex.Message));
    }

    return null;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you thats it :) It works perfectly for our solution.